# How to calculate proximity of corners to a point in a square

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Forgive me in advance for not necessarily knowing how to ask this question:
I would like to calculate the proximity to each of the four corners of a square given an arbitrary (single) input point P, but expressed as value between 0-1, so if the point P (x, y) was located at C for example, C's output value would be '1' and if it was located at A, C's value would be '0'.  There should be a mix between the corners.

What are the necessary steps to achieve this?
The context is that I'm building an application whereby the user inputs a location (the point) and I would like the outputs to be normalized as a list of values [0, 1, 0, 0] for example, representing [vA, vB, vC, vD] with B as the corner point.  In this case coordinate P would be [-1, 1].  If the point is [0,0] the output would be [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5].

[image]

Comment: There are the barycentric coordinates given three noncollinear points say E,F,G which are P=xE+yF+zG where x+y+z=1. These coordinates (x,y,z) are unique given the chosen noncollinear points E,F,G. [Some of x,y,z may be negative, which occurs when P is outside triangle EFG. However I don't know whether one can set up the same idea using four vertices of a square and get unique coordinates. Not saying it can't be done, but I don't know. [note in the case of barycentrics, the sum xE+yF+zG is computed viewing E,F,G each as a point with two coordinates and x,y,z as scalars.]

Comment: @coffeemath yes I had a friend tell me about barycentric coordinates and I too noticed that they're typically expressed with a third dimension.

Comment: I agree it seems like 3-d because of the three coordinates. But that is somewhat illusory because of the constraint x+y+z=1 on the three weights assigned to the base triangle's vertices. Without those constraints one doesn't have uniqueness, and I think odd things result.

Comment: Your problem might make sense if you give us the context of the problem ;)

Comment: It is not unique. For points inside unit square $[0,1]^2$, you can always do trivial bilinear interpolation like this: $P_{(x,y)} = (1-x)(1-y)A_{(0,0)} + x(1-y)B_{(1,0)} +(1-x)yD_{(0,1)} + xyC_{(1,1)}$

Comment: @KamalSaleh I edited my post.  Thank you for the nudge.

Comment: @jml The edit helps. If you can [edit] again to tell us how your application will _use_ those weights we may be able to help. But note that requesting four numbers normalized to sum to $1$ leaves three degrees of freedom, and it takes only two to locate the point, so any scheme will introduce asymmetry or nonuniqueness.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did not mean to ask them to sum to 1.  I do not care about the sum total.

Comment: @jml Then you should probably not call them weights. In a way that's worse - two degrees of freedom. Unless you can tell us what you will _do_ with these numbers we can't make a sensible recommendation. You might consider the reciprocals of the squares of the distances to the corners, normalized or not. That won't be defined at the corners, but you could use a large cutoff, (I think there's no point in further back and forth in comments.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd calculate the distance between P and a corner point, then divide this by the maximum possible length across the square (2$\sqrt{2}$) to get a percentage or decimal number, then subtract that from 100% for it to be an inverse of the distance.

Comment: Sounds great!  I'll try this asap but it seems like a good solution :)